# How to suppress operator overloading for get and set methods in Kotlin inspections?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-inspections

I am trying to create a custom `get` and `set` method but I would like to suppress the inspections warning `Function should have 'operator' modifier` only for these specific functions.

The following did not work:

```java
@Suppress("operator")
suspend fun get(key: K): V?

@Suppress("operator")
suspend fun set(key: K, value: V): String?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [IntelliJ Inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-inspection.html), and you can see options for turning it off by clicking on the light bulb, then clicking on the right arrow of the first drop down option.

[image]

You will find the option "Suppress 'AddOperatorModifier' for fun get". Choosing it will insert the line:

```
@Suppress("AddOperatorModifier")
```

The inspection can also be disabled globally in the IntelliJ settings:

[image]